# J turns carriage return into newline

Tags: console-application, carriage-return, j

I'm trying to implement a progress bar for a command line application, e.g.

```
[#####     ] 50% complete
```

I know I can just backspace to the start of the line and overwrite, but that seems so gross.  I'd rather use the carriage return to put the cursor at the first column and *then* overwrite.

The problem is that the J engine appears to not render the carriage return character, instead rendering a newline+carriage return.

Here is what I have tried:

`echo 'hi',(10{a.),'world'` (where `10{a.` is ASCII 10, i.e. carriage return) which prints

```
hi
world
```

`echo 'hi',(13{a.),'world'` (newline) which prints

```
hi
world
```

`shell 'printf "%s\r%s" hi world'` which prints

```
hi
world
```

`shell 'printf "%s\n%s" hi world'` which prints

```
hi
  world
```

Finally, I tried all of the above in JHS instead of Jconsole, with identical results.

From this, three things are apparent:

1. The J front ends turn the carriage return into a carriage return + newline.
2. The J front end also processes carriage returns generated externally (for example by printf) into newlines.
3. J *does* recognize a newline by itself as shown in the last example.

Any help?

Comment: You can try ANSI escape codes, though it's a long shot. Try `(ESC)[80D` instead of the carriage return (where `(ESC)` is character code 27), or `(ESC)[A` after a newline.

Comment: I can't find a source for this but afaik `CR`,`LF` and `CRLF` all produce the same line break in jconsole. Have you tried the ncurses library?

Comment: According to `~addons/docs/help/user/previous601.htm` it appears ANSI was deprecated for UTF-8 starting at J601.  Will give it a try though.

Comment: You might take a look at the first 4 demos in the studio menu of the jhs environment in j803. These are examples of putting html objects into the results returned. In particular demo 4 shows the way that they can be made interactive. If you were to hook up the progress of your event to the appropriate display you may have a way of updating in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugly but works:

```
   0$ stdout shell 'printf "99 problems\rno"'
no problems
```

## UPDATE - 50% less ugly!

Nicer to avoid calling `printf` from the shell:

```
   0$stdout 'hi world',(13{a.),'12'
12 world
```

## UPDATE - 75% less ugly!

Thanks to a comment from @Eelvex

```
   0$stdout 'hi world',CR,'12'
12 world
```

Comment: If you'll be using it a lot you may wish to make a utility verb, like this: `cr=: [ , CR , ]` at which point you can write `'hi world' cr '12'` and the like.